# Java: Getting proper context of "this" in anonymous action handler

Tags: java, android, andengine

I noticed a peice of code I was looking at, that the author used:

```
class MainClass
{
  protected int someVar = 1;

  private SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass(this, new SomeActionListener() {
    protected void onAction() {
      MainClass.this.someVar ++;
    }
  });

  public MainClass()
  {
  }
}
```

Note how he used `MainClass.this` to get the proper context of 'this' to change the scope back to `MainClass`. I've never seen this done before - can someone explain?

Comment: just as a note, since there is no other variable named `someVar` in the scope of the `onAction` method, the compiler could have figured out that `someVar` referred to the `MainClass` member field without the explicit notation of `MainClass.this`. The author of the code here was just trying to be explicit to make it clear to another person what variable was being incremented.

Comment: Look at this: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The anonymous instance is bound to the scope of the instance in which it is created. Therefore it can also access everything within. `this` would refer to the anonymous instance and `MainClass.this` to the instance in which the anonymous instance was created. If for example the `someClass` member would have been declared as `static`, you could not have used `MainClass.this`.